# Bootstrap 2 and working with the grid compared to Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I just inherited a project which unfortunately uses `Bootstrap 2`, I'm used to using `Bootstrap 3` but have never worked with version 2 before.

I have done a bit of reading on the differences and as I understand it the columns work by using `span*` where * indicates the amount of columns you want that element to span.

However I am confused on how you can change this depending on your different breakpoints?

For example in Bootstrap 3 you can do:

```
col-sm-4
col-md-8
```

How can you change the element like that in `Bootstrap 2`?

Comment: check [Migrating from 2.x to 3.0](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot! The bootstrap 3.x grid system has predefined classes for different devices - `col-xs-*`, `.col-sm-*`, `.col-md-*` and `.col-lg-*`.

Bootstrap 2.x have not. It has one system of predefined classes, made for one viewport only :

> The default Bootstrap grid system utilizes 12 columns, making for a
>   940px wide container without responsive features enabled. With the
>   responsive CSS file added, the grid adapts to be 724px and 1170px wide
>   depending on your viewport. Below 767px viewports, the columns become
>   fluid and stack vertically.

To achieve the same behavior in bootstrap 2.x as 3.x you must [include bootstrap-responsive.css](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive) that holds hardcoded `.span` widths (and a lot more) for different media sizes, practically the same as `col-xs-*` etc :

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
...
  .span3 {
    width: 166px;
  }
  .span2 {
    width: 104px;
  }
  .span1 {
    width: 42px;
  }
...
```

So in bootstrap 2.x `.span1` is the same as `col-xs-1`, `.col-sm-1`, `.col-md-1` and `.col-lg-1` depending on the viewport, *if* you have `bootstrap-responsive.css` included.

Comment: Thanks. So basically using `span*` will set that width for *all* screensizes and you'd have to handle other manipulations manually?

Comment: @Brett - Yes,  remember to include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` as stated in the mentionen responsiveness link. I have used that in several projects and it works well.